# Silverlight Accessing WCF and CrossDomainAccessPolicy without IIS

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

I have a Windows Service that exposes a WCF service and so I'm not using IIS.  I'm suddenly getting the famous SecurityException that mentions using a cross-domain policy when I try to access the service from a Silverlight app.  However, since I'm not using IIS, does that mean I need to have a web server on the *same* port as my WCF service just to serve this file?  Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add another service with webHttpBinding (REST) that serves out ClientAccessPolicy.xml file. Then in your Windows Service, you can start that endpoint along with the other one so that Silverlight clients can get the cross-domain policy file. You can find more information in below links:

- [Step By Step - Using Silverlight to Access a WCF Service Hosted In a Console Application](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=208)
- [Self hosted WCF service and enabling cross domain calls](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/1fa2f718-c6f3-41b0-a663-5e65876472ac)

Comment: Thanks - exactly what I needed.  I would expect this is a common use case, so I'm surprised it took so much.  Anyway, I guess it could've been worse.

Comment: Ditto.  Thanks for the info.  The first one was far more helpful to me than the second one.